# Is there any other policy need to be attached to create a role for aws glue databrew?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have tried to explore the new aws glue databrew service by connecting a data set from s3 bucket. But i am getting an error called **DataBrew does not have access to the role**.

I followed the steps for setting up IAM policies for databrew which are mentioned in the aws documentation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/databrew/latest/dg/setting-up-iam-policy-for-databrew-console-access.html

Did i miss any steps or is there any different policy for databrew.?

These are the policies i have used to create a role.

**1.AwsGlueDataBrewFullAccessPolicy**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "databrew:*",
            "glue:GetDatabases",
            "glue:GetPartitions",
            "glue:GetTable",
            "glue:GetTables",
            "glue:GetDataCatalogEncryptionSettings",
            "dataexchange:ListDataSets",
            "dataexchange:ListDataSetRevisions",
            "dataexchange:ListRevisionAssets",
            "dataexchange:CreateJob",
            "dataexchange:StartJob",
            "dataexchange:GetJob",
            "kms:DescribeKey",
            "kms:ListKeys",
            "kms:ListAliases",
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:GetBucketCORS",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
            "sts:GetCallerIdentity",
            "cloudtrail:LookupEvents",
            "iam:ListRoles",
            "iam:GetRole"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::databrew-public-datasets-*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "kms:GenerateDataKey"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "kms:ViaService": "s3.*.amazonaws.com"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:PassRole"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "iam:PassedToService": [
                    "databrew.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

**2.AwsGlueDataBrewCustomUserPolicy**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "PolicyForDatabrewUserRole",
"Statement":
[
    {
        "Sid": "ToUseDataBrewConsole",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "databrew:*",
            "glue:GetDatabases",
            "glue:GetPartitions",
            "glue:GetTable",
            "glue:GetTables",
            "glue:GetDataCatalogEncryptionSettings",
            "dataexchange:ListDataSets",
            "dataexchange:ListDataSetRevisions",
            "dataexchange:ListRevisionAssets",
            "dataexchange:CreateJob",
            "dataexchange:StartJob",
            "dataexchange:GetJob",
            "kms:DescribeKey",
            "kms:ListKeys",
            "kms:ListAliases",
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:GetBucketCORS",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
            "sts:GetCallerIdentity",
            "cloudtrail:LookupEvents",
            "iam:ListRoles",
            "iam:GetRole"
        ],
        "Resource": ["*"]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "ToGenerateKmskey",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
                "kms:GenerateDataKey"
        ],
        "Resource": ["*"],
        "Condition":
            {
                "StringLike":
                {
                    "kms:ViaService":
                    [
                       "s3.*.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "ToActOnUsersBehalf",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:PassRole"
        ],
        "Resource": ["arn:aws:iam::*:role/*"],
        "Condition": {
             "StringEquals": {
             "iam:PassedToService": [ "databrew.amazonaws.com" ]
             }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "ToAllowSampleDataSets",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "s3:ListBucket",
          "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::databrew-public-datasets-*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

**3.AwsGlueDataBrewSpecificS3BucketPolicy**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "PolicyForDatabrewToUseS3",
"Statement":
[
    {
        "Sid": "ToUseSpecificS3Buckets",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:PutBucketCORS",
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::<my bucket name>"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "ToAllowSampleDataSets",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "s3:ListBucket",
          "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::databrew-public-datasets-*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: did you updated the JSON with the S3 buckets that you have in your account? Also update your questions with error message and policy created.

Comment: Hi @PrabhakarReddy, i have attached the above polices in newly created role and error is mentioned in bold. As you mentioned i have given the s3 bucket name correctly in AwsGlueDataBrewSpecificS3BucketPolicy.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error message you are sharing, it appears that DataBrew is not able to assume the role you are providing. Here are the steps you can follow to debug

1. Log into AWS console
2. Navigate to the IAM console and open the role https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/roles/<<YOUR_ROLE>>?section=trust, and open the "Trust relationships"
3. Your role might be missing `databrew.amazonaws.com` from the list of "Trusted Entities".

If this is the issue, here's the solution

1. Click "Edit Trust relationship"
2. Add the following JSON policy and click "Update Trust Policy"

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "databrew.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, IAM will let DataBrew assume this role.